# Aws EKS Prometheus helm failed pod CrashLoopBackOff with log "trigger reload: reload request failed: Post \"http://127.0.0.1:9090/-/reload\"

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

I followed the steps here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prometheus/latest/userguide/AMP-onboard-ingest-metrics-new-Prometheus.html

In a nutshell, I installed the Prometheus community helm chart on my EKS cluster in AWS https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts.

My Kubernetes version is 1.27

The cluster node group has two t3.large nodes (8gb memory, 2vCPU)

After creation, I have:

Pods:

```
kubectl get pods -n prometheus

NAME                                                        READY   STATUS             RESTARTS         AGE
prometheus-alertmanager-0                            1/1     Running            0                142m
prometheus-kube-state-metrics-69b5df7dc4-kfqc2       1/1     Running            0                142m
prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter-dkksq            1/1     Running            0                142m
prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter-fzr5z            1/1     Running            0                142m
prometheus-prometheus-pushgateway-847c6f4d57-dz5wx   1/1     Running            0                142m
prometheus-server-5fbb47548d-sxm72                   1/2     CrashLoopBackOff   32 (3m58s ago)   142m
```

Pod logs:

```
 kubectl logs prometheus-server-5fbb47548d-sxm72 -n prometheus

....
level=error ts=2023-08-04T17:45:27.636671778Z caller=runutil.go:100 msg="function failed. Retrying in next tick" err="trigger reload: reload request failed: Post \"http://127.0.0.1:9090/-/reload\": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9090: connect: connection refused"
```

Deployments:

```
kubectl get deployments -n prometheus
NAME                                       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
prometheus-kube-state-metrics       1/1     1            1           144m
prometheus-prometheus-pushgateway   1/1     1            1           144m
prometheus-server                   0/1     1            0           144m
```

Describe failed deployment:

```
kubectl describe deployments prometheus-server -n prometheus

...
 Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Available      False   MinimumReplicasUnavailable
  Progressing    False   ProgressDeadlineExceeded
```

The EBS volumes have successfully bound.

It seems that the prometheus-server pod is stuck in CrashLoopBackOff because it can't connect to itself on 127.0.0.1:9090

I have been searching for an answer all day and trying different things but can't solve the issue.

My helm values looks like this:

```
## The following is a set of default values for prometheus server helm chart which enable remoteWrite to AMP
## For the rest of prometheus helm chart values see: https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/prometheus/values.yaml
##
serviceAccounts:
  server:
    name: amp-iamproxy-ingest-service-account
    annotations: 
      eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam:###########:role/service-role/Amazon_EventBridge_Invoke_Api_Destination_###########
server:
  remoteWrite:
    - url: https://aps-workspaces.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/workspaces/#############/api/v1/remote_write
      sigv4:
        region: eu-west-1
      queue_config:
        max_samples_per_send: 1000
        max_shards: 200
        capacity: 2500
```

I can't figure this out,
please help! I'm sure someone else has struggled with the same issue because I can't find much info on this. Why is it failing? What Can I do to fix it? Thanks in advance

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/). --- Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: It's not off-topic, it is 100% related to programming.

However you comment is off topic and I am actually looking for an answer not an argument so please refrain from your policing, it's not welcome.

 If it was off topic then every single tag that was given as an option to me should be removed from stack overflow. Perhaps you should log a support query if you're confused.

Comment: It is related to infrastructure, not programming. Since you have a problem with the setup an AWS service, as described in a guide of AWS, maybe you want to open a support ticket with AWS.